# How to read all unnamed column on dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have dataframe value data like this

```
    acolumn     bcolumn
70  0.503462    0.6
71  0.480712    0.5
72  0.505440    0.5
73  0.553907    0.5
74  0.344214    0.5
```

How to read the first unnamed column at dataframe? I already tried using iloc(), columns[0] and still the output is acolumn, I want the output is like this

```
70, 71, 72, 73, 74
```

I want to use that data to labelling my graph at my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is the index of the dataframe.

Try:

```
df.index
```

Cheers.